# Martin Fierro chapter division name

Tags: translation, literature

The book [Martin Fierro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mart%C3%ADn_Fierro) has been divided into (in Spanish) "Cantos", chapters written in prose. What is their name in english?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word you're looking for is...***canto***.

> canto: one of the main or larger divisions of a long poem.
>
> 1580-90; < Italian < Latin cant (us) singing, song, equivalent to can (ere) to sing + -tus suffix of v. action; cf. cant1, chant
>   [Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/canto)
>
> "*La Ida* is divided into 13 cantos and has 2,306 verses" [Embodying Argentina](https://books.google.fr/books?id=83y8ijZ8EekC&pg=PA153&lpg=PA153&dq=%22divided+into%22+%22martin+fierro%22+%22cantos%22&source=bl&ots=R1wAXOFHGc&sig=6Pr5Z2NX9hGqmKmpjHdmZELkZBQ&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNkoq41rXJAhWFORoKHaqlBVgQ6AEIIDAC#v=onepage&q=%22divided%20into%22%20%22martin%20fierro%22%20%22cantos%22&f=false)